# Code not working. Radio button validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript for validation of radio button.

HTML-

```
 <form name="formreg" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">  
     <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" /> Male<br />  
     <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" /> Female<br />  
     <input value="Submit" onclick="return inputval()" type="submit" />  
 </form>
```

JS-

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function inputval() {  
        var $XIForm = $('form[name=XIForm]');  
        if ($("form[name='formre'] input[type='radio']:checked").length != 1) {  
            alert("Select at least male or female.");  
            return false;  
        }  
        else {  
            var gender = $("input").val();  
            //alert(gender);  
            $XIForm.submit();  
            alert(gender);  
        }  
    }  
</script>
```

Can anybody pls help with this code.

Comment: you may add what is nit working in your solution. that may give better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code. You will have to create a form and validate it on submit.

HTML:-

```
 <form name="myForm" action="targetpage.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();"   method="post">  
        <label>Gender</label>&nbsp&nbsp  
        <input type='radio' name='XIGender' value='Male' id="XImale" />Male  
        <input type='radio' name='XIGender' value='Female' id="XIfemale" />Female</td>  
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="XISubmit" />  
    </form>
```

JS:-

```
 function validateForm() {  
        if (validateRadio(document.forms["myForm"]["XIGender"])) {  
            alert('All good!');  
            return false;  
        }  
        else {  
            alert('Please select a value.');  
            return false;  
        }  
    }  

    function validateRadio(radios) {  
        for (i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {  
            if (radios[i].checked) return true;  
        }  
        return false;  
    }
```

Hope this will help you. :)
Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `simple button` instead of a `submit button`, this way you can stop the form from submitting if something is wrong and only submit it on your `else` branch.

`<input value="Submit" onclick="return inputval()" type="button" />`

http://jsfiddle.net/J62Qq/

Also, you had some typos (wrong form name).

```
   function inputval() {  
    var $XIForm = $('form[name=formreg]');  //you had wrong name here
    if ($("form[name='formreg'] input[type='radio']:checked").length != 1) {  
        alert("Select at least male or female.");  
        return false;  
    }  
    else {  
        var gender = $("input").val();  
        //alert(gender);  
        $XIForm.submit();  
        alert(gender);  
    }  
}
```

The problem with not using a submit button is that the form can not be submitted without JavaScript, but I think this is ok in your case as anyway you do not want to submit the form if you can not validate it.